# Complex animation using QPropertyAnimation in QT 4.7.1

Tags: c++, qt, animation

I'm implementing an algorithm that calculates a path for disk robots in the plane and want to visualize the movement of the robots along this path.

A **path** is a vector of **subpaths**, where each subpath is a list of 
`pair<QPointF,QPointF>` elements. The first QPointF represents the current position of A, and the second of B. The two robots move simultaneously from one pair to the other.

I was able to successfully visualize the movement of the robots within the subpath using `QPropertyAnimation` for each robot and `QtParallelAnimationGroup` for the two `QPropertyAnimation` objects.

The problem is that for every subpath I have to display a certain graph (a set of lines/edges and points) on the screen that stays static throughout the animation of the subpath and changes only when the robots move to the next subpath.

I tried to add the graph to the display every time the `QPropertyAnimation` finishes the current animation of the subpath but it seems that the animation runs on the same thread as the code so I can't use `while (propAnim->state() != QAbstractAnimation::Stopped){}`.

Does anyone has suggestions how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured how to solve it.

For every `QtParallelAnimationGroup`, responsible for the animation of the subpath, I connected its `finish()` signal to a method that displays the next graph on the screen.